# dumpdata, too many arguments?

Tags: django

We just migrated to a new server,  and dumpdata via this command (modernpolitcs is app name):

## python manage.py dumpdata modernpolitics > /dump/backup.json

worked on old server, but now is not working on new server (after tying to reinstall all dependencies).

The error I'm getting is, "Error: Unable to serialize database: get_db_prep_value() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)"

Googled the error and just found a couple 'resolved' tickets about old django development. Any ideas what the problem could be?

python 2.7.2
django 1.4

I'm able to dump one model, e.g. modernpolitics.question .. hmm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> get_db_prep_value() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

This error sounds familiar: django with  multi database support takes a new `connection` parameter for model fields.

If you are using any third party fields or subclassed `Field`s they need to be updated to accept / pass this new argument.

The traceback will reveal which field is breaking.

Comment: awesome, traceback revealed that it was a custom model field causing the problem. I'm reading the documentation of custom model fields and its unclear what the connection parameter is supposed to be. Any ideas or links to better explanations? Just the string indicating which database connection to use e.g. 'default'?  EDIT: tried passing the suggested string and no errors thrown!

Comment: You probably just should use get_prep_value  instead of get_db_prep_value

Comment: Since it looks like the [`get_db_prep_value` method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/a4c23f70deda5321687cd1f759c65a35d161e793/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L616-L625) doesn't actually use the `connection` argument, you can just pass in `None` as the value to resolve this error. Look in your custom field code for something like this `self.get_db_prep_value(value)` and replace it with something like this `self.get_db_prep_value(value, None)`